# Create new columns based on frequency of array from one column

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

I have dataframe like this:

```
     column_1     column_2
    ['a','c']            1
    ['b','c']            2
['a','b','c']            1
```

Now I want to add 3 columns (a, b and c), based of frequency of occurrence.

Desired output:

```
a   b    c   column_2
1   0    1          1
0   1    1          2
1   1    1          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the names of the columns which you will create beforehand (so, you can store the names in a list), the following approaches do it without shuffling.

**If you just need to know if array contains the value:**

- Spark 3.1+

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(['a','c'], 1),
       (['b','c'], 2),
       (['a','b','c'], 1)],
      ['column_1', 'column_2']
  )
  cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  arr_cols = F.array([F.lit(x) for x in cols])
  arr_vals = F.transform(arr_cols, lambda c: F.array_contains('column_1', c).cast('int'))
  df = df.select(
      *[F.element_at(arr_vals, i+1).alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      'column_2'
  )
  df.show()
  # +---+---+---+--------+
  # |  a|  b|  c|column_2|
  # +---+---+---+--------+
  # |  1|  0|  1|       1|
  # |  0|  1|  1|       2|
  # |  1|  1|  1|       1|
  # +---+---+---+--------+
  ```
- Spark 2.4+

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(['a','c'], 1),
       (['b','c'], 2),
       (['a','b','c'], 1)],
      ['column_1', 'column_2']
  )
  cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  df = df.withColumn('arr_cols', F.array([F.lit(x) for x in cols]))
  arr_vals = F.expr("transform(arr_cols, c -> cast(array_contains(column_1, c) as int))")
  df = df.select(
      *[F.element_at(arr_vals, i+1).alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      'column_2'
  )
  ```

**If you need to know the count of occurrences:**

- Spark 3.1+

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(['a','c'], 1),
       (['b','c'], 2),
       (['a','a','b','c'], 1)],
      ['column_1', 'column_2']
  )
  cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  arr_cols = F.array([F.lit(x) for x in cols])
  arr_vals = F.transform(arr_cols, lambda c: F.size(F.array_remove(F.transform('column_1', lambda v: v == c), False)))
  df = df.select(
      *[F.element_at(arr_vals, i+1).alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      'column_2'
  )
  df.show()
  # +---+---+---+--------+
  # |  a|  b|  c|column_2|
  # +---+---+---+--------+
  # |  1|  0|  1|       1|
  # |  0|  1|  1|       2|
  # |  2|  1|  1|       1|
  # +---+---+---+--------+
  ```
- Spark 2.4+

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame(
      [(['a','c'], 1),
       (['b','c'], 2),
       (['a','a','b','c'], 1)],
      ['column_1', 'column_2']
  )
  cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  df = df.withColumn('arr_cols', F.array([F.lit(x) for x in cols]))
  arr_vals = F.expr("transform(arr_cols, c -> size(array_remove(transform(column_1, v -> v = c), false)))")
  df = df.select(
      *[F.element_at(arr_vals, i+1).alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(cols)],
      'column_2'
  )
  ```

Comment: when there's null it's returning count as -1, can I add anywhere ```na.fill(0)``` in current query? I can also replace -1 to 0 in the end, but just want to check if I can make any modification in current query.

Comment: It's caused by `size`, because it gets null instead of array. It's best to add `df.replace(-1, 0, cols)` at the end. This would not harm anything else and it's very clean and readable. Otherwise you would need to use `when/otherwise` logic inside the code which would clutter it and make it even harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your pyspark dataframe is:

```py
df.show()

+---------+--------+
| column_1|column_2|
+---------+--------+
|   [a, c]|       1|
|   [b, c]|       2|
|[a, b, c]|       1|
+---------+--------+
```

You can first `explode` column `column_1`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_1 = df.withColumn("explode_col1", F.explode("column_1"))
df_1.show()
+---------+--------+------------+
| column_1|column_2|explode_col1|
+---------+--------+------------+
|   [a, c]|       1|           a|
|   [a, c]|       1|           c|
|   [b, c]|       2|           b|
|   [b, c]|       2|           c|
|[a, b, c]|       1|           a|
|[a, b, c]|       1|           b|
|[a, b, c]|       1|           c|
+---------+--------+------------+
```

Then use `groupby` and `pivot` to count elements (and keep only columns you want):

```py
df_2 = df_1.groupby('column_1', 'column_2').pivot('explode_col1').count().na.fill(0).drop('column_1')
df_2.show()
+--------+---+---+---+
|column_2|  a|  b|  c|
+--------+---+---+---+
|       1|  1|  1|  1|
|       1|  1|  0|  1|
|       2|  0|  1|  1|
+--------+---+---+---+
```

And if you want to have it all in one line:

```py
df.withColumn("explode_col1", F.explode("column_1")).\
groupby('column_1', 'column_2').pivot('explode_col1').count().\
na.fill(0).\
drop('column_1').\
show()
```

Comment: Hey I tried this and when I check the count before and after doing explode and pivot, count of later dataframe is less, shouldn't that be equal? What I mean:


df_1 is original dataframe with count 100k and when I perform this operation the final df shouldn't also have same count? But instead it has less than 100k records? Do you know where I might be losing record?

Comment: Hi, It's hard to say without looking at data. But my first guess is that there might be some NULL values which were excluded during explode or groupby. Not sure, but just guessing.